# getMergedRanges() array output is out of order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column of merged cells and am trying to modify a specific merged cell. For some reason, the array of ranges that I get back when calling the getMergedRanges() method is out of order. Here's my code:

```
  var column = spreadsheet.getRange('H8:H151');
  var mergedCells = column.getMergedRanges();
  mergedCells[0].setValue('This is a string');
```

Instead of setting the value of the first merged cell in the column, it would modify the 13th merged cell... Is this a bug with App Script or did I do something wrong?

[Click here to see a similar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rgr4.png)

I want to edit merged cell #2 but when I modify the output by accessing index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rgr4.png), it would modify some other cell. The result is always different each time.

Comment: Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating `Instead of setting the value of the first merged cell in the column, it would modify the 13th merged cell`?

Comment: Yes they appear to be out of order for me also.  I created 10 merged ranges of 3 cells horizontally  and I start from row 1 to row 5 and then from row 10 to row 6 and here's the order of the array. `Range: A8:C8
Range: A7:C7
Range: A1:C1
Range: A2:C2
Range: A3:C3
Range: A4:C4
Range: A5:C5
Range: A10:C10
Range: A9:C9
Range: A6:C6`

Comment: But they are not guaranteed to be ordered.  Are they?  Do yourself a favor and unmerge all cells. You shouldn't merge cells at all.

Comment: I think this is intended behavior. Why is it affecting you? It seems like a very easy thing to workaround.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same as you and I'm not facing the same problem. Could you maybe share a sample sheet to test on your specific case? Make sure we are able to copy it.

Comment: @Raserhin - here's the link to the sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IT7GoKZbTWTz5CIGtr8IKE_ua-P4lcX1LhPj9C7o3HQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your sheet I understood what your problem was. This seems to only happen when the number of merged cells is high.

This does indeed look like a bug on Google's side. So I have reported a [bug on your behalf](https://issuetracker.google.com/148999577). You can click on the `+1` to give it more attention to be solved quickly.